# Fetch parent record from children using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables tasks and groups with the association as

//Groups has many tasks

```
        db.groups.hasMany(db.tasks, { as: "tasks" });
        db.tasks.belongsTo(db.groups, {
        foreignKey: "groupId",
         as: "group",
        });


I have tried this but no luck,
        await Task.findAll({where: { userId: id },
        include: [
        { model: db.groups, as: "groups" },
        ],
        });
```

How can I retrieve groups from tasks using sequelize ? Simply, I want to fetch parent record from child using sequelize.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost achieved your goal. Just correct an alias in `include` option:

```
await Task.findAll({where: { userId: id },
  include: [
   { model: db.groups, as: "group" },
  ],
);
```